# Air pollution api javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing an air pollution app, but I'm unable to view either the city or the pollution index via geolocation.
How can I change the code to display both the city and the pollution index in my app?

I'm using the following API:
https://aqicn.org/json-api/doc/#api-Geolocalized_Feed-GetGeolocFeed

Here is the JS code:

```
const cityElement = document.querySelector(".city span");
const indexElement = document.querySelector(".indexAir span");

const air_key = '';
const air = {};

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      let longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      getData(latitude, longitude);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation in not supported by this browser");
  }
}

function getData(latitude, longitude) {
  let api = `https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:${latitude};${longitude}/?token=${air_key}`;

  fetch(api)
    .then(function(response) {
      let data = response.json();
      return data;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      air.index = air.aqi;
      air.city = air.city;
    })
    .then(function() {
      showData();
    })
}

// DISPLAY INFORMATIONS
function showData() {
  cityElement.innerHTML = `${air.city}<span> </span>`;
  indexElement.innerHTML = `${air.index}<span> </span>`;
}
```

```
            //GET AIR POLLUTION FROM SEARCH  BAR

         btn_search.onclick = function() {
            let city = document.getElementById('city').value;

            let api = `https://api.waqi.info/search/?token=${air_key}&keyword=${city}`;

          fetch(api)
          .then(function(response){
         let data = response.json();
         return data;
         })
       .then(function(data){
        air.city = data.data[0].station.name;
        air.index = data.data[0].aqi;
       air.time = data.data[0].time.stime;
    
      })
     .then(function(){
      let elemCity = air.city;
      let pollution = air.index;
      showData();
      changeBackground(pollution);
     })
   }





     // CHANGE BACKGROUND INDEX AIR

      function changeBackground(pollution){
          if(pollution<=50){
          index.style.background = "rgb(58, 194, 58)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(58, 194, 58)";
     }else if(pollution>=51 && pollution <=100) {
          index.style.background = "rgb(242, 245, 54)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(242, 245, 54)";
    }else if(pollution>=101 && pollution <=150) {
          index.style.background = "rgb(243, 156, 57)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(243, 156, 57)";
    }else if(pollution>=151 && pollution <=200) {
          index.style.background = "rgb(245, 22, 22)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(245, 22, 22)";
    }else if(pollution>=201 && pollution <=300) {
          index.style.background = " rgb(136, 69, 245)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(136, 69, 245)";
    }else if(pollution>300) {
          index.style.background = "rgb(160, 59, 59)";
          index.style.border = "rgb(160, 59, 59)";
    }else {
        index.style.background = "lightgrey";
        index.style.border = "lightgrey";
    }
 }
```

If I wanted to search for a city after typing it using the enter key, what function should I type?
Another thing, would it be possible to create an error message when a city is not found?

Comment: You're assigning `undefined` to `air.index` and `air.city`. Is it supposed to be `air.index = data.aqi`?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights yes

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I've change air.index = data.aqi but I have the same result.

Comment: debug.... console.log() is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air quality data returned from the feed API has a [shape](https://aqicn.org/json-api/doc/#api-City_Feed-GetCityFeed) similar to:

```json
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "aqi": 20,
        /*...*/,
        "city": {
            "geo" : [ 
                52.52006,
                13.4049,
            ],
            "name": "Berlin, Germany",
            "url": "https://aqicn.org/city/germany/berlin"
        }
    }
}
```

You should be accessing `aqi` and `city` from the `data` field in the feed response like so:

```js
function getData(latitude, longitude) {
  let api = `https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:${latitude};${longitude}/?token=${air_key}`;

  fetch(api)
    .then(function(response) {
      let data = response.json();
      return data;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
       air.index = data.data.aqi;
       air.city = data.data.city.name;
    })
    .then(function() {
      showData();
    })
}
```